# Learning classifier system frameworks

Tags: optimization, machine-learning

For some time already I am studiyng and applying machine learning methods. Recently for some particular problem, where methods like SVM, RF, neural nets etc. failed I got limited success with genetic programming, which was quite new area for me in practice at the moment.
But right now it looks like, I really need to implement something like [Learning classifier system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_classifier_system).

So the question is, are there any existing frameworks for LCS implementation ? 
To be more precise I am looking for frameworks on any language from the list: Java, Python, R, Matlab.

Thanks.

P.S.: I am still not sure if this is a correct place to ask my question, should I go with it to CrossValidated instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many implementations. Here's a list on one of the main LCS research community websites:

http://gbml.org/category/software/

Unfortunately I haven't used any extensively, so I can't say which would be best. There's a python implementation in the first page of listings though.

Comment: Not very helpfull site actually, but my own search showed that there is nothing else out there. Thank you for the link and your help.

Answer (score 1):

some time ago (in a galaxy...) I wrote a python versiom of the XCS LCS. Thi version was a "literal" translation of the Java verison.

You can find it in my downloads web page:

[Download LCS page (go to the bottom of the page)](http://www.dacya.ucm.es/jam/download.htm)